# How do you play music clips longer than 30 seconds in Rec Room custom rooms?

Tags: rec-room

I want to add my own music to my custom room in Rec Room. The audio clip is 80 seconds long and I want it to play when someone hits a button.

When I tried recording the audio, I realized samplers only hold 30 seconds of audio, which is not enough for my song. How are all these other rooms playing songs that are multiple minutes long and how can I do the same?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Option 1: Sampler Speed

You can speed up the audio clip prior to recording so that it fits into 30s. Then use the green speed input pin on the sampler to speed it back down when playing it. The playback speed is `g/10` (where `g` is the value from the green input). So values in the range from 1 - 9 speed down the playback.

Note that the playback speed is with pitch shift, so you will have to use the pitch shifting speedup in your audio editor.

The drawback is that the audio quality will be reduced, especially in the higher frequency areas. Sometimes that is sufficient, you will have to judge that yourself for your use case.

### Option 2: Event Sequence

Break down your audio clip into fractions that are 30 seconds long, and record them to multiple Samplers. You will probably want to make sure there is a bit of overlap.

Then use a construct that is called [Event Sequence](https://rec-room.fandom.com/wiki/Circuit_Diagrams#Event_Sequence) in the wiki to trigger them in a sequence.

There are 2 Options to implement an Event Sequence:

#### Option 2.1: Selector Based Event Sequence

[image: Selector Based Event Sequence]

In this example, the event sequence triggers stage lights, but you can of course replace them by samplers. The version above can be configured using the Selector configuration. Also note that this version will keep the Sampler input at a constant 1, so make sure that you switch to the next sampler before the previous one stops playing, otherwise it will loop.

#### Option 2.1: State Machine Based Event Sequence

[image: State Machine Based Event Sequence]

As before, replace the Stage Lights by Samplers.

This version is configured by configuring each state to have a Minimum Time in State of 30 seconds (a bit less for overlap). It will also only trigger each sampler with a pulse, so there is no risk of repeating samplers here.